# Getting number of articles in specific date range

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to have my articles counted per day in certain date period, so I could get array of 40 counts of 40 days.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `caption` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author_id` (`author_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

I am not an expert in MySQL, so farthest where I gone is this:

```
$sql  = 'SELECT date_added FROM articles ';
    $sql .= 'WHERE date_added > ' . '"' . $mysql_datetime_start . '" AND ';
    $sql .= 'date_added < ' . '"' . $mysql_datetime_end . '" ';
    $sql .= 'GROUP BY date_added ';
```

And than I wanted to go into loops, but there must be some better solution with single query.

This is for a calendar on my site, so one query could save a lot of processor time.

Hope someone will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's `DATE` function to separate out just the date portion of the `DATETIME` column, then group by it.

```
SELECT DATE(date_added), COUNT(*) FROM articles
WHERE date_added BETWEEN $mysql_datetime_start AND  $mysql_datetime_end 
GROUP BY DATE(date_added);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT DATE( date_added ), count(*) FROM articles 
  WHERE date_added > '" . $mysql_datetime_start . "'
  AND date_added < '" . $mysql_datetime_end . "' 
  GROUP BY DATE( date_added )"
```

be sure to sanitize your date time start and end before using them.